Confusion on Spivak Calculus on Manifolds 4-24 and 4-27: what's wrong with my counterexample?
Let $c_{R, n}: [0, 1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 - 0$ be given by $c_{R, n}(t) = (R\cos(2\pi n t), R\sin(2\pi n t))$.
Problem 4-24 in Calculus on Manifolds asks:

If $c$ is a singular $1$-cube in $\mathbb{R}^2 - 0$ with $c(0) = c(1)$, show that there is an integer $n$ such that $c - c_{1, n} = \partial c^2$ for some $2$-chain $c^2$.

This integer $n$ (winding number) should be unique, per problem 4-27.
However, I've seemingly cooked up the following simple "counterexample" and am not sure what's wrong with it.
Let $c = c_{2, 1}$ and $n$ be any integer.
We can construct $c^2(t_1, t_2) = t_1c(t_2) + (1 - t_1)c_{1, n}(t_2)$.
Then,
\begin{align*}
\partial c^2(t) &= c^2(1, t) - c^2(0, t) - c^2(t, 1) + c^2(t, 0)\\
&= c(t) - c_{1, n}(t) - [tc(1) + (1 - t)c_{1, n}(1)] +  [tc(0) + (1 - t)c_{1, n}(0)]\\
&= c(t) - c_{1, n}(t)
\end{align*}
where the last equality comes from the fact that $c(0) = c(1)$ and $c_{1, n}(0) = c_{1, n}(1)$.
Thanks in advance!
--pebble.

Did you check that your $c^2$ never hit $0$?

@TedShifrin Thank you! This was the detail I missed.
